# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - Even when Firebase.InitializeApp() is called, the error persists

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, flutter-web

I hope someone could help me with this issue, I have tried all the examples given above, however the same error is still showing

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
>
> at Object.f [as app] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js:1:16867)

this my main.dart initial code

```
void main() async {

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  developer.log('${Firebase.apps.length}', name: 'main.dart');
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
  };
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(Firebase.apps.length == 0){
      return Loading();
    }
    else
    return StreamProvider<UserData>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: MAIN_TITLE,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber, accentColor: Colors.amber[200]),
        home: MyHomePage(
          title: HOME_PAGE,
        ),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/home': (BuildContext context) => new Wrapper(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/" />

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project." />

    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="web_product_unitrade" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png" />

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

    <title>web_product_unitrade</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
       
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="error-element"></p>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
     
    <script type="module">
      import { firebaseConfig} from '/lib/configuration/firebase-config.js';
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>

    <script>
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener("flutter-first-frame", function () {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register("flutter_service_worker.js");
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When running the app is runs properly locally, however when running in release mode, the following error is generated.

```
zone.dart:1171 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at Object.f [as app] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js:1:16867)
    at Object.afQ (http://localhost:52254/main.dart.js:9835:63)
    at Object.ald (http://localhost:52254/main.dart.js:8221:29)
    at http://localhost:52254/main.dart.js:14458:5
    at afM.a (http://localhost:52254/main.dart.js:4531:71)
    at afM.$2 (http://localhost:52254/main.dart.js:29996:23)
    at Object.L (http://localhost:52254/main.dart.js:4517:19)
    at Object.P9 (http://localhost:52254/main.dart.js:14482:10)
    at http://localhost:52254/main.dart.js:71366:8
    at http://localhost:52254/main.dart.js:71361:55
```

Comment: With Flutter web, if you update index.html, you may need to close the whole app and run "flutter clean" then "flutter packages get".... Another suggestion, try changing `firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js` to `firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js` because that's what's shown on the [Flutter Web introduction](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web) at Flutter Fire website

Comment: @Uni can you please specify which json file is missing??

Comment: @osaxma I have changed the firebase-app.js package but still it's showing the same error. I did try flutter clean and then flutter run the error persists

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the firebase guide over [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview).
Also make sure to check if you google-services.json file is added in the android app and the GoogleService-Info.plist is added in the iOS app.

Comment: Yes, I have followed the instruction on building a web app using flutter.